# Email apps cannot read the file I'm trying to attach

Tags: android, file, email

I write a file into the SD. I Know the file is OK because using ASTRO app or Gmail app or Yahoo  app, I can see it and I can also attach it from them but when I try to attach the file from my app the thing is quite different. When I choose gmail or yahoo app they can't read the file. But if I choose the default app the email is sent correctly with the file attached.

Here is my code. THANKS!!

Inside AndroidManifest
   uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"

Where I make the file

```
File ruta_sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File f;

// Creo la carpeta;
File folder = new File(ruta_sd.getAbsolutePath() + "/Torno");
folder.mkdirs();

f = new File(ruta_sd.getAbsolutePath() + "/Torno/","Torno.xml");

// Just trying
f.canRead();

OutputStreamWriter fout = new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(f));
fout.write(c); <-- c is a String in xml format

// Just trying
fout.flush();

fout.close();
```

Now, where I try to attach it

```
String ruta = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/Torno/Torno.xml";
Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sendIntent.setType(getMimeType(ruta));
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse(ruta));
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "el tema");
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "el cuerpo del mensaje");

// Just trying
sendIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);

startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, "Title:"));`
```

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "can't read the file". What specific error messages are you receiving? Also, why are you including `FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION` when you are not using a `ContentProvider`? You might also wish to consider using `sync()`: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/12/saving-data-safely.html

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering. I'm from Spain and the messages are in Spanish. I'm going to try to translate them. Gmail app says: "Se ha detenido la aplicación" what means "The app has been stopped". This happen when I press the button to send it but the file is there as attached. Yahoo app says: "Acceso de lectura denegado. El archivo seleccionado no se puede leer" what means "Read access denied. The selected file cannot be read". FLAG_GRANT_....? I was only trying. I'll read the link about sync(). Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably there is something wrong with your path. Change:

```
String ruta = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/Torno/Torno.xml";
...
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse(ruta));
```

to:

```
File ruta = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "/Torno/Torno.xml");
...
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(ruta));
```

and see if that helps (along with getting rid of `FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION`, and perhaps trying `sync()`).

Answer (score 0):

At the end, It worked!!! I don't really know what was happening. I was trying with my phone as emulator with eclipse without installing the app and the e.getMessage() of the exception was: "/storage/sdcard/Torno/Torno.xml: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)"

Finally, I thought to install the app and it worked!! This is the current code:

```
btnAceptar.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override 
             public void onClick(View arg0) { 
                     // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
                     String contenido="";

                     File fichero = null;

                   if (rdXML.isChecked()){ 
                          contenido = creaFichero(1,Integer.parseInt("" + txtAno.getText()),Integer.parseInt("" + txtMes.getText()));
                          fichero = grabarFichero(contenido, "Torno.xml");
                   } 
                   else{ 
                          contenido = creaFichero(2,Integer.parseInt("" + txtAno.getText()),Integer.parseInt("" + txtMes.getText()));
                          fichero = grabarFichero(contenido, "Torno.txt");
                   } 

                   if (fichero==null){ 
                           Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"No hay datos para ese mes !!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                           toast.show(); 
                   } 
                   else{
                       Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                       sendIntent.setType(getMimeType(fichero.getAbsolutePath()));

                       sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(fichero));
                       sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "el tema");
                       sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "el cuerpo del mensaje");
                       startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, "Title:"));
                   } 
           } 
   });

public static String getMimeType(String url){
    String type = null;
    String extension = MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(url);
    if (extension != null) {
        MimeTypeMap mime = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
        type = mime.getMimeTypeFromExtension(extension);
    }
    return type;
}

private File grabarFichero(String c,String n){

    File file = null;

    try {
        // Creo la carpeta;
        File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/Torno");
        folder.mkdirs();

        file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Torno", n);
        OutputStreamWriter outw = new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(file));
        outw.write(c);
        outw.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {} 

    return file;
}
```

THANKS!!!